# Angular.js getting ng-options list from previous ng-options selection in object of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, nested, ng-options

I have an object:

```
object: {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"name1",
    "number":"number1",
    ...,
    "subObject":[{
        "id":"1",
        "name":"subName1"},
        {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"subName2"}
    ]};
```

I am using ng-options to select the object.name value, but have a separate ng-options where I want to see only the "subObject" list of names associated with the object.name value selected first. This Object[object] is, obviously, more complex than the example above, but that is the gist of the structure.

Currently, to gain the value of the object.name value I have:

```
<label>Object Name</label>
<select ng-options="object.name as object.name for object in Parent.objects track by object.name" ng-model="mainName" ng-value="Parent.thisState.objects.name"></select>
```

Is it possible to gain the list of subObject's name list when solely selecting the name of the object rather than the whole object first?

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider this is your main object containing sub objects.

```
$scope.objects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'object one',
  subitems: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'subitem one of obj 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'subitem two of obj 1'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'subitem three of obj 1'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'object two',
  subitems: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'subitem one of obj 2'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'subitem two of obj 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'subitem three of obj 2'
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'object three',
  subitems: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'subitem one of obj 3'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'subitem two of obj 3'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'subitem three of obj 3'
  }]
}];
```

and this would be your html,

```
  <select ng-model="s1" ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in objects"></select>

<select ng-model="s2" ng-options="subobj.name as subobj.name for subobj in s1.subitems" ng-disabled="!s1"></select>
```

by default subObjects select field will be disabled (as it doesnt have any parent value). as soon as you select the value in mainObject seclect field , the second field populated with parents's selected subObjects

Comment: Unfortunately, this will return the first value as the entire object instead of just the name. The value I required is solely the name of the object. That leaves the subitems as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the intended result in different ways.

This following example is a possible solution, where on selecting the object from the first select we give them directly to a $scope variable to be used by the second select.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="selectedFromList" 
    ng-options="object.subitems as object.name for object in list track by object.id"></select>
    <select ng-model="selectedFromSubList"
    ng-options="subitems as subitems.name for subitems in selectedFromList"></select>
 </body>
```

On the first select we say that we want to display the name of the object `as object.name` and the manageable object will `object.subitems` that will be stored in the ng-model `ng-model="selectedFromList"`
On the second select we just going to iterate over the object in the model `selectedFromList` and display the `subitems.name`.

Working [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BaS9z5Z0FKf0aMplKX0d?p=preview)

**Edit**

For the problem that you described as comment I will sugest the use of a filter, so the name can prevail on the ng-model of the first select. I'm assuming that the name is unique since is the name that you want to send to the "API".

**Filter code**

```
.filter('mapArray', function() {
  return function(array, name) {  
    if (!angular.isArray(array)) return array;
    var filter = array.filter(function(value){return value.name === name.name;})[0];
    if (filter === undefined) return [];
    return filter.subitems;
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="selectedFromList" 
    ng-options="object.name as object.name for object in list"></select>
    <select ng-model="selectedFromSubList"
    ng-options="subitems as subitems.name for subitems in 
(list |  mapArray:{name :selectedFromList})"></select>
  </body>
```

Working [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1n5FO3C4qTiJUyJ7rame?p=preview)

Comment: The same issue is found here. The first select's value sent to the API must be the object.name value. So, though the object.name values are shown when you use `object.subitems as object.name` the value that is being sent to the API is `object.subitems` and not `object.name`.

Comment: @brettwbyron i modified the answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I decided that I would keep my code abstracted and create a service function to obtain the first objects' as well as a service function to obtain each subObject's id in each parent object.

It looked something like this:
`self.getObjects = function() {
    MyService.getObjects()
        .then(function(results) {
            self.objects = results.objects;
        });

self.getSubObjectsByObjectId = function(objects, id) {
    objects.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (obj.id === id) {
            self.sub = obj.sub;
        }
    });
};`

Comment: `forEach()` is a function I've written that belongs in a library folder I use in all of my applications.